# Problema al generar APK y al mostrar Sha1 mediante consola

Tags: java, android

Buen día, hace algunos días formatee mi pc y guarde las keys(.jks) para poder generar nuevamente mis aplicaciones de la tienda, el problema es que cuando trato de generarlos me aparece el siguiente mensaje
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Segun el mensaje yo altere u olvide mi llave pero yo solo la copie y pegue en una carpeta.

Otro problema que tengo es al tratar de obtener el codigo sha1 por consola, este problema esta para mis llaves nuevas y antiguas, sale este mensaje
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy preocupado y un poco estresado ya que he investigado en todo internet y no encuentro como solucionar este problema, espero que me puedan ayudar con alguna idea para solucionarlo
De antemano, Muchas gracias

Comment: Cual es el comando que ejecutas ? keytool -list -keystore nombreKeystore?

Comment: Este:    C:\>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152\bin\keytool" -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\oddye\Dropbox\Subidas desde cámara\key.jks"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En cuanto al primer error:

> Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect

es importante agregar el correcto password que definiste inicialmente para tu Keystore, de lo contrario no podrás acceder a las propiedades del Keystore.

El segundo error

> java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.String"

Veo que usas lenguaje español y en ocasiones ocurre este error cuando no usas lenguaje ingles ¿?, en este caso define el lenguaje ingles:

```
-J-Duser.language=en
```

y posteriormente los comandos que deseas, ejemplo:

```
keytool -J-Duser.language=en -list -keystore archivoKeystore...............
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias!, en lo del idioma tenias razón, pero en el otro problema no creo que sea error mio ya que siempre use la misma clave para firmar todos mis APKs, estoy revisando este post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29997688/android-studio-cannot-recover-key de otra persona que le pasa lo mismo

Comment: @AlvaroFabianM recuerda que hay un Password de Keystore, pero además un alias de la llave y un password de la llave, tal vez los estas confundiendo. Espero que no lo haya modificado otra persona para asignar otro password.

Comment: Hola Jorge muchas gracias por la ayuda al final el problema era que se me había de olvidado las contraseñas que había utilizado el día que firme la aplicación. Siempre había usado las mismas pero ese día había tenido problemas al usar mapas y no recordaba que las había cambiado, al final tuve que tratar con todas las contraseñas que uso hasta que encontré la combinación